# ID card and wrapping it identification

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I have the following ID, and I want to detect it, and warp it. 
Main problems

1. That method doesn't work with all kind of images dataset, I can't find the best contour, please suggest better ways for preprocessing it?
2. I get two contours, one for the background and one for the ID, I wanna just filter others stuff and get just the ID.

[image]

Result:

[image]

```
document_img = cv2.imread(dataset + imfile)
document_img = imutils.resize(document_img, width=460)

src = imutils.resize(document_img, width=460)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(document_img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

document_type = document_types.ID_front.value
equ = cv2.medianBlur(gray, 1)

fil = cv2.bilateralFilter(equ, 9, 11, 17)

thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(fil, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, \
                           cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 11, 2)

cv2.imshow('canny', thresh)
cv2.waitKey()
im2, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = sorted(contours, key=cv2.contourArea, reverse=True)[:5]
screenCnt = None
# loop over our contours
for c in cnts:
    # approximate the contour
    peri = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.015 * peri, True)

    # if our approximated contour has four points, then
    # we can assume that we have found our screen
    if len(approx) == 4:
        screenCnt = approx
        break

cv2.drawContours(src, cnts, -1, (0, 255, 0), 3)
cv2.imshow('contours', src)
cv2.waitKey()

# cv2.drawContours(im, appr, -1, (0,255,0), 3)
points_list = [[i[0][0], i[0][1]] for i in screenCnt]

left = sorted(points_list, key=lambda p: p[0])[0:2]
right = sorted(points_list, key=lambda p: p[0])[2:4]

print("l " + str(left))
print("r " + str(right))

lu = sorted(left, key=lambda p: p[1])[0]
ld = sorted(left, key=lambda p: p[1])[1]

ru = sorted(right, key=lambda p: p[1])[0]
rd = sorted(right, key=lambda p: p[1])[1]

print("lu " + str(lu))
print("ld " + str(ld))
print("ru " + str(ru))
print("rd " + str(rd))

lu_ = [(lu[0] + ld[0]) / 2, (lu[1] + ru[1]) / 2]
ld_ = [(lu[0] + ld[0]) / 2, (ld[1] + rd[1]) / 2]
ru_ = [(ru[0] + rd[0]) / 2, (lu[1] + ru[1]) / 2]
rd_ = [(ru[0] + rd[0]) / 2, (ld[1] + rd[1]) / 2]

print("lu_ " + str(lu_))
print("ld_ " + str(ld_))
print("ru_ " + str(ru_))
print("rd_ " + str(rd_))

src_pts = np.float32(np.array([lu, ru, rd, ld]))
dst_pts = np.float32(np.array([lu_, ru_, rd_, ld_]))

h, w, b = src.shape
H, mask = cv2.findHomography(src_pts, dst_pts, cv2.RANSAC, 5.0)

print("H" + str(H))

imw = cv2.warpPerspective(src, H, (w, h))
im =  imw[int(lu_[1]):int(rd_[1]), int(lu_[0]):int(rd_[0])]  # cropping image

cv2.imshow('ff', im)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: can you change the background? It makes things difficult if you have background similar to the object color.

Comment: That's not a usual case of that background, but check that picture with a better background https://imgur.com/a/xFzue8e

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Hough-transform to detect the rectangle of the i.d.
You first need to use some edge detection operator (I see you are already using Canny). Then run the Hough transform for lines on the edges image. Then just draw the top lines the transform has found. Ones you got the lines surrounding the i.d, it is easy to get the rectangular area it contains and do what ever you want with it.

I downloaded your image and used to following code to achieve the results below (just played with it for a couple of minutes, i'm sure the parameters can be better tuned):

```
 import cv2
 import numpy as np

 img = cv2.imread(folder + 'image.jpg')
 gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
 kernel = np.ones((5,5),np.float32)/25
 gray = cv2.filter2D(gray,-1,kernel)
 edges = cv2.Canny(gray,400,600,apertureSize = 5)
 cv2.imshow('image',edges)
 cv2.waitKey(0)

 lines = cv2.HoughLines(edges,1,np.pi/180,15)
 for i in range(8):
      for rho,theta in lines[i]:
           a = np.cos(theta)
           b = np.sin(theta)
           x0 = a*rho
           y0 = b*rho
           x1 = int(x0 + 1000*(-b))
           y1 = int(y0 + 1000*(a))
           x2 = int(x0 - 1000*(-b))
           y2 = int(y0 - 1000*(a))
      cv2.line(img,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(0,0,255),2)

 cv2.imshow('image',img)
 cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Edges image:
[image]

Results of Hough transform:
[image]

Comment: Thanks so much, some questions, can you do the warpping? and what about other light conditions, canny doesn't work in all cases ?

Answer (score -3):

You can also use a Pre-Trained model to identify the id-card in the image and then crop it !

[image]

Check This repo, where am a contributor :
https://github.com/mesutpiskin/id-card-detector